# File download doesn't seem to work, for a Play Framework 1.2 based Java application deployed on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using ClearDB MySQL on heroku, rather than Postgres given by default. My code works perfectly fine on my local machine. Here is my download file method:

```
public static void downloadFile(long id) throws Exception {

final Article doc = Article.findById(id);
        notFoundIfNull(doc);

    User current_user = User.find("byEmail", Security.connected()).first();

    if(!current_user.equals(doc.author)){
        SelectedArticles selectedArticle = SelectedArticles.find("byArticleAndReviewer", doc, current_user).first();
        if(selectedArticle == null)
        {
             SelectedArticles newSelected = new SelectedArticles(current_user, doc);
             newSelected.save();
             selectedArticle = newSelected;
        }
        selectedArticle.download();
    }

    response.setContentTypeIfNotSet(doc.article_pdf.type());
    renderBinary(doc.article_pdf.get(), doc.pdfName);
}
```

This is waht I see in the Heroku logs:

```
←[36m2012-05-09T01:29:41+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerE
xception
←[36m2012-05-09T01:29:41+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  ... 2 more
←[36m2012-05-09T01:29:41+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m  at play.mvc.results.RenderBinary
.apply(RenderBinary.java:167)
```

Comment: Can you verify that the connection is being made correctly?  Can you go into the ClearDB console through your http://api.heroku.com/myapps and verify that your data is there as you expect it to be?

Comment: I am using MySQL workbench & I can see all my data

Comment: Cool.  Do you know which line is causing the NPE?

Comment: That's the starnge part, since the same code works perfectly fine on my local machine in DEV mode. How can I figure out which line is causing NPE, I am cluless. I am sharing the heroku logs here:

Comment: ←[36m2012-05-09T03:50:32+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Oops: NullPointerException
←[36m2012-05-09T03:50:32+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2012-05-09T03:50:32+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m An unexpected error occured cause
d by exception NullPointerException: null

Comment: I have observed this, initially download works fine after clean up of the database. But, as I do commit changes on to heroku.. this download excpetion occurs.

Comment: We need to narrow down what line is causing the NPE.  Also it might be good to get the same version of MySQL locally as ClearDB uses.  But I'm not sure what version they use.  You might have to contact them or use the Workbench to find out.

Comment: $ heroku ps
Process   State           Command
--------  --------------  ------------------------------------
web.1     up for 1m       play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_O..
worker.1  crashed for 1m  play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_O..

Comment: The worker thread crashes when I try to download, heroku ps shows that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11076/discussion-between-raul-and-james-ward)